# common-mode noise in single-ended parallel wire

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, electromagnetic, signal-integrity

As we all know that common-mode voltage is the average of voltages in two lines Vcm = (V1+V2)/2. So as shown in the figure below, a transmission line composed of two parallel wires above a ground plane, there will be common-mode noise of 8V coupled into ground. [image]

Everything is clear to me by now, however, when I am thinking another case, as shown in the picture below, where the voltage on second line is 0V (GND, same as the ground plane), based on the same equation, the common-mode noise will be 5V. However, to me it is no longer a differential pair, it is actually a single ended transmission line, can single ended transmission line have common-mode noise (coupled into the ground plan in this case)? This is where I confuse about. Thanks for your answers! [image]

Comment: In lumped circuits, 0V is what we define it to be, and everything else is relative to that.  The earth itself can have an overall charge, but it's still defined as earth ground.  Your circuit ground may be at a different potential; that's why you have to provide a scope ground to a floating circuit to make sure your circuit and scope have the same opinion as to what constitutes 0V.  For this reason, in a single-ended circuit it makes little sense to talk about common-mode and differential-mode signals (although the finite value of C means there's not really ground either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So as shown in the figure below, a transmission line composed of two parallel wires above a ground plane, there will be common-mode noise of 8V coupled into ground.

If the 8 V is constant, then this isn't common mode **noise**. It's a common mode bias.

If the 8 V fluctuates randomly, then the that fluctuation is common mode noise.

For example if there is a 100 mV rms fluctuation on top of the 8 V, then you have 8 V common mode bias voltage, and 100 mV rms common mode noise.

> can single ended transmission line have common-mode noise (coupled into the ground plan in this case)?

If the return conductor is only weakly earthed (for example, connecting it to earth through a 1 megohm resistor is fairly common), or if it's only earthed at one point, and there are random stray magnetic fields through the loop between the transmission line and earth, then you will see the return line potential (at different points along the line) fluctuate around 0 V, which will contribute to common mode noise.

You might also see this behavior called a *ground loop*.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you a follow up question? For case 2, if I remove the ground plan or move it to infinite far, then there would be no common-mode noise in the parallel wire. However, what will happen if the two wires are in different length? I think there will be noise (radiation) generated from the wires?

Comment: Regardless of where the ground plane is, you still need to define some reference point for potentials in your circuit. Your transmission line can still have common mode noise relative to that point.

Comment: Different length wires is likely to produce some differential-to-common-mode conversion. It would be determined by the differential signal rather than random, so wouldn't really be noise per se.